# Minimization of convex functions on dense subspaces

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis

I want to consider the Moreau envelope $\psi_j$ of a proper, convex, lower semicontinuous function $\psi$ over a Banach space $V$ on dense (finite dimensional) monotonically increasing subspaces $V_m$, i.e. $V_m \subset V_{m+1}$ and
\begin{equation*}
\overline{\bigcup_{m\in \mathbb{N}} V_m } = V.
\end{equation*}

The Moreau envelope is also proper, convex, lsc and additionally coerciv so the minimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\min_{v_m\in V_m} \psi_j(v_m)
\end{equation*}
has a solution $\phi_{jm} \in V_m$ for each $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Now my question: Is the sequence of minimizers $\{\phi_{jm}\}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded ( and maybe even independent of $j$)?

Comment: Without additional assumptions, existence of minimizers is not guaranteed (think of linear functionals). You could add, for example, coercivity.

Comment: Yeah, of course, thanks. I just forgot to mention this. However, the question stays the same.